# Knockout cannot rebind observable

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, knockout.js, froala

Inside my program, I use Froala rich text editor to write some texts, put some images etc. And for some specific reasons, I create a tag with ko.observable binding and I submit everything to Drupal, erasing the tag with the binding just before submitting. After I can take this information from Drupal again (no tag with this bindings anymore). So, in order to edit this information again I create the same binding again. However, this time this binding does not work anymore. I simplified all of my javascript code below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function create_image_table() {
        if (!document.getElementById("img_div0"))
            $('<div id="img_div0" style="border : 1px solid black;  width=80%"  class="asd row"/>').appendTo(document.getElementsByClassName("fr-element fr-view")[0]);
        $('<div id="ilk0" class="my_ilk col-sm-6" contenteditable="false"/>').append($('<div id="caption0" style="font-weight:normal; height: 50px;" data-bind="text: captionName0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="caption_class"  contenteditable="false"/>')).appendTo($("#img_div0"));    
    }
    function create_image_observables(){
        myViewModel['captionName0'] = ko.observable('CAPTION : ');
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,document.getElementById('caption0'));
    }
    var myViewModel = {
        edit_fields : function() {
            this.captionName0('CAPTION : ' + document.getElementById('caption_input').value);
        } 
    };
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
    document.getElementById("editor_content_button").addEventListener("click", submit);

    var images = document.getElementsByClassName("asd row");
    for (j=0;j<images.length;j++) { 
        create_image_table(0, "");
        create_image_observables(0, "","","","","");    
    }
    function submit () {
        create_image_table(0, "");
        create_image_observables(0, "", "", "", "", "");
        var content_to_send = document.getElementById("img_div0").parentNode.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/g,"<"); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {mycontent: content_to_send, title: "", author: "" },
            url: "submit_2.php",
            success: function(response) {
                if(response > 0) { 
                    window.location = ($(this).attr('href') + 'rte_2.php?id='+response).replace("undefined","") ;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        $('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor({toolbarButtons: ['undo', 'redo' , '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|' ,'fullscreen', 'inlineStyle', '|', 'insertLink', 'paragraphFormat','|', 'insert','insertHTML'],})    
    });
});
```

In submit_2.php in order to erase these tags, I use :

```
$tags= $xpath->query('//div[contains(@id,"ilk")]');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {   
    $tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);    
}
```

Then, I get all information from Drupal and show them again in the same format as before (I add the tag with the binding again). But binding lost its observable feature.

I also tried using cleanNode and removeNode functions inside submit function instead of erasing it in submit_2.php, however, I got the same result again. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Knockout like this is not going to work out well. Knockout is not just a library you can pop in to do data binding; it wants to handle all DOM manipulation. You need to figure out how to do what you want to do in a Knockout way, or figure out how to do it without Knockout.

Comment: @Roy J Actually I am sure that I should use knockout. However I could not figure out how to do it since when sending the information I should erase some tags and when I got back I should create the same tags with the same bindings.

Comment: Possibly assign the `innerHTML` to a scratch div, find the tags in that div, remove them, then take the `innerHTML` from there.

Comment: This also did not work :(

Comment: If you can set up a Fiddle that shows what you're trying do that isn't working, maybe I (or someone) can figure it out.